# Workflow where one field is changed while the workflow is in process

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a requirement in my list where I need to set up a time period of four days if one of the fields equals one out of the four choices available for that certain field. When this certain choice is picked, the workflow begins setting a timer of four days.  When this four days has finished, an email is sent out to remind a user to finish the task the field is referring to.  If in those four days the field is edited and changed to a different choice out of the four choices, it will overwrite the intial workflow start.  How do I use the workflow to stop reminder from going out but continuing with the other steps in the workflow that come after this step?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SPD 2013, you can create a workflow with a pause timer action which will pause the workflow for 4 days.  If I remember right, having it check the field at this point won't see any changes in the intervening 4 days.  The solution is to put the field check in a loop, which will force the workflow to look at the item again and check the field.

Answer (score 0):

I would add 2 parallel tasks... wait on change and pause for 4 days. Have the parallel section complete if any of these complete